# Alternatives to array of chars

Tags: c++

I would like to know what standard container could I use as an alternative to `char board[8][8]` from a performance point of view. The board needs to be accessed frequently for both reading and writing. up to 1 million of new board might be constructed during the algorithm. Only three possible values are allowed for each element: -1, 0, 1, so the total number of useful bits for a board actually is 128. I thought of a custom type built around std::bitset<128> with all the required (inline) operator[], ==, =, etc defined for accessing it as 2d array, but I am not sure this would speed up the access compared to the original char[8][8]. I also don't care about gains in memory usage, this is not a problem.

Comment: Bitset wouldn't speed things up, it would actually make it slower, and by far. Perhaps, uint32_t [8][8] will be even faster.

Comment: Are you sure this is your performance problem anyway? I'd assume that the algorithm you're applying to this data is the real bottleneck. Measure it and see. `std::array` would be my choice here though.

Comment: Do you even have a problem with access the way things are now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a `std::array<signed char, 64>` and access it as `a[8 * i + j]`*. No point going into sub-byte granularity, since those 64B will probably be in the same cache line anyway and you get quick access like that. You could even try an array of `int`s for comparison; it might be that word-sized access is even faster. Only profiling can tell.

*) Or even `std::array<std::array<char>, 8>, 8>`, as rightly commented. Same thing, essentially, though perhaps even easier to use.

Comment: `std::array< std::array< signed char, 8 >, 8 >` gets you the same thing without modifying index computations in the existing code.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Yeah, also true :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you do not care about memory usage, **do not use a bitset**. In fact, the fastest solution will probably be one that is the easiest to use for the hardware.

You will have to profile, but I suspect using a word-sized 1d array would be the fastest:

```
long board[64];
```

Obviously, `board[x][y]` becomes `board[x * 8 + y]`;

If you want you can make a C++ class interface for this, make sure to have the functions inlined though.

---

Remember, always profile! There is a chance that a `signed char` is faster than a `long`, depending on the compiler and architecture.

Comment: There's no difference between `board[8][8]` and `board [64]`. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Violet Giraffe: Of course not! `board[8][8]` requires __two__ pointer dereferences to get to the actual value, which could be expensive. There is a chance the optimizer will do some trickery, but I wouldn't rely on it (profiling is always your best friend in these situations).

Comment: @nightcracker C arrays are not pointers, they only look like pointers if you squint hard enough. Accessing a two-dimensional array requires one memory access, unless the whole array is hoisted to registers and the index is constant.

Comment: @nightcracke: x86 specifically has the capacity to do two-dimensional indexing in instructions- and it's not two pointer de-references, it's two pointer *indexes*.

Comment: Oh, excuse me, I often confuse C arrays with pointers (probably because it is easier to understand them that way). @DeadMG: I had no idea x86 had instructions capable of two-dimensional indexing, that's pretty impressive!

Comment: @nightcracker: there is no 2-dim indexing. Static multidimensional arrays are basically linear arrays that require some math (like 8*i + j) upon indexing.

Comment: I think you're confusing each other. If you malloc a two dimensional array int[][] with individual dimensions into one int** you will quickly understand that it usually does in fact have two dereferences for element access. It is however possible to treat an int[][] as an int* as well.